# Regexp question mark (in emacs)

Tags: regex, emacs

I'd like to ask what the following emacs regular expression means (if anyone wonders, this is the regexp that erlang-mode uses for matching a single-quoted atom):

`'\\(?:[^\\']\\|\\(?:\\\\.\\)\\)*'`

specifically I'm having trouble finding explanations for three things.

First, the question mark which supposedly should either make the preceding item optional or specify that the preceding quantifier make lazy, but there is no item or quantifier here, only the start of a new group so what effect does it have here?

Second, the escaped apostrophe. Why would you need to escape the apostrophe?

Third, the quadruple escape `\\.`, wouldn't this leave you with an escaped backslash and a `\.` which would make it an invalid regexp?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `"[^\\']"`
>   Second, the escaped apostrophe. Why would you need to escape the apostrophe?

Firstly note that In Emacs regexp syntax, `` \` `` matches the start of the string, and `\'` matches the end of the string. In multi-line strings this is different to the more familiar `^` and `$`, which match the beginning of a line and the end of a line.

However that is not relevant within a character alternative (square brackets), so this sequence is actually matching any character other than a backslash or an apostrophe.

**Edit:**

So from the comments, this is still causing confusion, so let's break it down:

`"'\\(?:[^\\']\\|\\(?:\\\\.\\)\\)*'"`

That code evaluates to this string/regexp:

`'\(?:[^\']\|\(?:\\.\)\)*'`

`'` matches an apostrophe

`\(?:foo\)*` matches zero or more `foo`

`foo\|bar` matches either of `foo` or `bar`

`[^\']` matches any character other than a backslash or an apostrophe

`\(?:\\.\)` could (in this case, being a non-capturing group which occurs exactly once) be rewritten as simply `\\.`, and matches a backslash followed by any character other than a newline.

`'` matches an apostrophe

So the whole thing matches a single-quoted string in which:

- any other single-quotes must each be preceded by a backslash
- any backslash must be paired with another non-newline character (which could also be a backslash)

Which of course sounds like a typical string syntax in which backslashes can be used to escape special characters, including backslashes themselves and any instances of the delimiting quote character.

Comment: Ok, so the need to escape the apostrophe is  because of its special meaning outside character classes?

Comment: But then why is there no need to escape the initiating and terminating apostrophes?

Comment: No, the point is that you *cannot* have an escaped apostrophe in an Emacs regexp. A plain apostrophe matches an apostrophe. If you prefix a backslash to an apostrophe you will either make it mean something other than an apostrophe, or else (in a character alternative) you will simply have both a backslash *and* an apostrophe.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for being slow, but I'm still having some problem interpreting the original regexp.

Comment: Damn enter key. Anyway, with you explanation I would take it to mean "an apostrophe followed by  a group consisting of either any character except the end of the string or a group of a backslash and any other character. This group is repeated 0 or more times and followed by an apostrophe. This seems a little strange to me (not at I'm absolutely sure that this is a good regexp).

Comment: I've edited the answer to explain in detail. (Also note my previous paragraph which pointed out that the special meaning of `\'` does not apply within a character alternative.)

Comment: Great, thank you for taking the time to explain. Sorry for being so slow, but I think my understanding was a bit hampered by my preconception of what the regexp _should_ evaluate to. Am I right to think that this is a rather convoluted way to express this regexp (disregarding the fact that the erlang documentation for  atoms makes no mention at all of backslashes or dots...)?

Comment: You're welcome. I think the only convoluted part was wrapping the `\.` in the non-capturing group syntax for no apparent reason. Perhaps that's a remnant from an earlier version.

Answer (score 0):

First: (?: groups multiple tokens together without creating a capturing group. This allows you to apply quantifiers to the full group.

Second and third, I think those are escaped bars. Each pair means `\`, and the quadruple means `\\`. So, its not scaping apostrophe at all.

Comment: I see what you mean about my first and last point, thanks for the help. In emacs however you have to use double escaping so for example `\\(` mean the start of a group. This would mean that \\' is an escaped apostrophe, right?